# What causes the occasional hiccups in UI transition on chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, frontend

for example:

```css
.class-name {
  transition: height 300ms ease
}
```

sometimes the hiccups are glaringly obvious. It happened way to fast to be 300ms.

Hiccups also may happen when using `setTimeout` to produce animations.

So what causes them?

Comment: Difficult to say without a MCVE.

Comment: This is a bit like asking why your engine might act sluggish sometimes....could be related to  variety of different systems from fuel to electrical to mechanical to environmental